# Cloud storage build file in chunk

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Looking for an example on how to build the file in cloud storage dynamically. Below is my use case:

1. Java application will query big query for data
2. Using pagination in big query, data will be pulled by page window
3. After having the data from BQ, will persist each chunk in cloud storage.
4. After all chunks have been uploaded, complete file upload.

The challenge in here is cloud storage file is immutable so once you have created the object in GCS, you can no longer reopen it unless you overwrite the same file.
Tried to explore using streaming and [resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads) feature and based on my understanding it needs the file to be ready prior to uploading.

If this is not possible, my only option now is to upload each chunk as different file and use cloud storage compose feature to merge these chunks into a one file. This is very costly given that you need to create multiple request to GCS just to complete one file.

Comment: Why do you think composing a Cloud Storage object from multiple parts is "very costly"? That is the best method. The cost of 10,000 Class A API operations is five pennies.

Comment: @JohnHanley basing from this comment in github, https://github.com/googleapis/gcs-resumable-upload/issues/132#issuecomment-603493772

Comment: Managing pricing is important. Trying to save 5/1000s of a penny and then spend thousands of dollars in software engineering to accomplish those savings. Technically, using object combines is far superior to a single multi-part upload for files larger than a few hundred megabytes.

Comment: yes, pricing is very important to us, given the load of users trying to hit our application and do this operation everytime it's a compounding cost. And agree, better to upload in smaller pieces than dropping the whole file in one upload request.

Answer (score 1):

If your final file format is CSV, JSONL (line), AVRO or Parquet, you can use the table export feature. only one file will be generated if you export less than 1Gb.

- Java application query BigQuery and sink the result in a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE `myproject.mydataset.mytemptable`
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
) AS
SELECT ....
```

- Java application performs a [table export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#java)

That's all.

Comment: yes this is my original implementation but trying to not be dependent too much with big query. This is technically correct but I'm looking for other option.

Comment: If you want to be the most efficient (in term performance and thus of cost (because you pay your processing time, more efficient you are, less processing power your need, cheaper it is)), you need to stick to the Cloud Provider tools and best practices. You can't be as efficient as BigQuery if you build a similar (and less optimized) solution on your side (in addition of the cost of the development and maintenance).